# Identifying, Describing a Binomial-type Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

Fix $p \in (0, 1), N, M \in \mathbf{N}_{\geqslant 1}$. It is well-known that if $X \sim \textbf{Bin} (N, p)$ and $Z \sim \textbf{Bin} (M, p)$, then $Y = X + Z$ is marginally distributed as $Y \sim \textbf{Bin} (N + M, p)$.

Now, write $K_M (X \to Y)$ to denote the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$, i.e.

\begin{align}
K_M (X \to Y) = {M \choose {Y - X}} p^{Y-X} (1 - p)^{M - Y + X}.
\end{align}

One can then write out the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$ in two ways:

\begin{align}
\Pi(X,Y) &= \mathbf{B}_{N, p} (X) \cdot K_M (X \to Y) \\
&= \mathbf{B}_{N + M, p} (Y) \cdot K_{M,N}^* (Y \to X),
\end{align}

where by Bayes' rule, one can compute

\begin{align}
K_{M,N}^* (Y \to X) = {Y \choose X} { {N + M} \choose N}^{-1} {{N + M - Y} \choose {N - X}}^{-1},
\end{align}

which is supported on $\max {(0, M - Y)} \leqslant X \leqslant \min { ( N, Y ) }$.

I remark quickly that it is **not** an accident that $K_{M,N}^*$ does not depend on $p$; all of the $p$ terms cancel out in the application of Bayes' rule. It is a priori not obvious to me why this should happen, but also not completely shocking; I suspect there's some intuitive explanation involving sufficient statistics or something to that effect. In any case, that's not important right now.

---

My question is then: *does this conditional distribution $K_{M,N}^*$ have a name?*

---

At a first glance it looks like a hypergeometric distribution of sorts, but on closer inspection, it doesn't quite match up. If it doesn't have a name, I'd still be happy with references which describe some of its properties in a bit of detail. It would also be nice to know if there is an efficient way to simulate this distribution.

A related question is what happens when one replaces every *Binomial* distribution above with a *Negative Binomial* distribution. In this case, the conditional distribution is given by

\begin{align}
\tilde{K}_{M,N}^* (Y \to X) = {Y \choose X} { {N + M} \choose N}^{-1} {{N + M + Y} \choose {N + X}}^{-1} \cdot \frac{N + M + Y}{N + M} \cdot \frac{N}{N + X} \cdot \frac{M}{M + Y}.
\end{align}

I would also be interested to learn about the properties of this distribution; I'll take what I can get at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer (i.e. not a reference / a name as requested) but an intuitive explanation why this is independent of $p$.

There are $M+N$ coins in a row, of which you know $Y=y$ are heads (and the rest are tails). Importantly, any of the ${M+N \choose y}$ ways of designating the subset of heads is equiprobable. Then $X =$ how many coins in the leftmost $N$ are heads?

Clearly $p$ does not appear anywhere in the above description.  $p$ controls how likely it is to get $Y=y$ heads in the first place, and it disappears once you condition on $Y=y$.

Great question re: the name - I'd like to know too.